# which the best between the find () method and the first () method when I retrieve specific data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

```
$data['list'] = $this->adminModel->where('nip', $nip)->first();
```

or

```
$data['list'] = $this->adminModel->where('nip', $nip)->find();
```

**$nip** is admin code unique, not primary key

Comment: The answer to this post should explain it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116186/codeigniter-4-models-find. For these kinds of questions it's good practice to dig through the CodeIgniter User Guide.

Comment: What do you mean by "the best"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter 4 Models->find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116186/codeigniter-4-models-find)